# Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized' uploading training images to custom vision

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-custom-vision

I'm trying to complete this sketch2code tutorial by AI School https://aischool.microsoft.com/en-us/services/learning-paths/sketch2code/sketch2code-lab/train-an-object-detection-model

Step 9 of the tutorial says:

> Enter the command `dotnet` run and press the enter key.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019  could that be the problem?

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
   at Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.CustomVision.Training.TrainingApi.GetDomainsWithHttpMessagesAsync(Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.CustomVision.Training.TrainingApiExtensions.GetDomainsAsync(ITrainingApi operations, CancellationToken cancellatio
nToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.CustomVision.Training.TrainingApiExtensions.GetDomains(ITrainingApi operations)
   at Import.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Harry\Downloads\AISchoolTutorials\sketch2code\Import\Program.cs:line 29
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.CustomVision.Training package.

1. Open your terminal and go to the Import folder
2. Run the following command `dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.CustomVision.Training --version 2.0.0`
3. Open Program.cs and replace this line:

   `TrainingApi trainingApi = new TrainingApi() { ApiKey = trainingKey };`

   with this line:

   `CustomVisionTrainingClient trainingApi = new CustomVisionTrainingClient(new  ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(trainingKey)) {Endpoint = endpoint};`

   make sure to replace ENDPOINT with your yours from [customvision.ai](https://www.customvision.ai/)